# How to update the layout file in observer

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, event-observer, layout-update

```
public function CodeOrdeStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {       
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder();
            $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getEntityId());
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
            $order->setStatus("canceled");
            $order->save();
            Mage::log($order->getState(),true,'cancelorder.log');


        }
```

i want to update the my custom layout file inside this event

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="orderscancel/index" name="orderscancel_index" template="orderscancel/cart.phtml"/>   
    </reference>    
</checkout_cart_index>
```

I tried

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate('Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <js>path/to/rahul.js</js>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>');
    Mage::app()->getLayout()->generateXml();
```

I have used the event sales_order_payment_cancel in config.xml

```
<events>
    <sales_order_payment_cancel>
        <observers>
            <change_order_status>
                <class>Ipp_Orderscancel_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>CodeOrdeStatus</method>
            </change_order_status>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_payment_cancel>
</events>
```

But it didn’t worked, please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Rahul,what you want to achieve? are you want to add a js file using observer?

Comment: yes, i need to add some java script code whenever my event triggered through observer

Comment: Where is your config.xml?? Paste that code also

Comment: Asish, check the updated question

Comment: Do you checked that your observer is firing??

Comment: yes, Its firing

Comment: Is their way to  add a js file,when my event triggered through observer

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong path here. To manipulate the layout programmatically, you don't need to write XML.

This XML code

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs">
        <js>path/to/rahul.js</js>
    </action>
</reference>
```

translates to this PHP code:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addJs('path/to/rahul.js');
```

(provided that `loadLayout()` has been called before, so that the "head" block already exists, but is not rendered yet)

Comment: thanks, but it gives the layout error

Comment: Now that I think about it, it makes sense: `sales_order_payment_cancel` is triggered in a request where no layout is loaded, the response is just a redirect to `sales_order/view`: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d409dff20e992e97546568974399c456958299f9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php#L176 - please update the question with more details what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: I have added the product to cart and done the checkout through the paypal,
now in paypal if i cancel the payment it will return to the cart page, if i click on the back button from the browser it will redirect to the paypal. And if i do the payment then it will pay.But in my order history it shows as the "canceled"  then "order processing" and "Preparing for Delivery"

Comment: so for that i have used the event "sales_order_payment_cancel", from that i want to add a script only when my cancel event triggered. so that i can block the browser back button through the script.
thanks